# Activity Grid and Note Preview is not working after upgrading to version 6.1

Tags: acumatica

I have customized and Added a tab in sales orderto display the task like activities tab in opportunity.

I had a similar problem and got solution through my previous posting

**Activity grid and Notes Preview is not in sync and it is not displaying proper data**

It is working fine in Version 5.3.x and once upgraded to 6.1, i am facing issue in refreshing the notes

I have made following changes in my view, since EPActivity is not available in Version 6.0

```
public PXSelect<CRActivity, Where<CRActivity.noteID, Equal<Current<CRActivity.noteID>>>> currentactivities;
```

Since I am not able to user grid with preview, I have used data grid and a HTML editor to show task notes. The notes value refreshes based on the focused row.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data view used for previewing note as below:

```c
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.CR;

namespace DemoPkg
{
    public class SOOrderEntryPXExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public PXSelect<CRPMTimeActivity, Where<CRPMTimeActivity.noteID,
                                          Equal<Current<CRPMTimeActivity.noteID>>>> CurrentActivity;
    }
}
```